# Compare tag text value with a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare the value of a tag obtained by query selector in the DOM with a given variable.

So far I've only managed the use of "contains" function, but I need to compare with an equality function.
The DOM element I need to obtain is "span:badge" and the variable to compare is "current_id".

This is the code I need to change:

```
var $a = $('span.badge:contains("' + current_id + '")').closest('a');
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
    var current_id = window.location.pathname.replace('/califications/','');
    if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(current_id, 10))){
        var $a = $('span.badge:contains("' + current_id + '")').closest('a');
        $($a).addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('#middle_column > div > h1').html("No kid selected");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="kid_list">
 <t t-foreach="kids" t-as="kid">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a t-attf-href="/califications/{{kid.id}}" t-attf-class="nav-link"><t t-esc="kid.name"/>
    <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: none;"><t t-esc="kid.id" /></span>
    </a>
  </li>
 </t>
</ul>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: please add an [mcve] to the question for faster resolution - Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Added example @blurfus

Answer (score 0):

To use `contains` seems right, but you need to do further, because `contains` also matches `aa` and `ab` if you search for `a`.

```
const $badges = $('span.badge:contains(`${current_id}`)');
const targetEl = null
$badges.each((i, e)=>{
  if(e.text() === current_id){
     targetEl = e.
  }
})
```

`targetEl` should be what you need, or you will also do `targetEl.closet("a")` if you want to get the `a`.

Comment: Tried with this code and is not working in my case. I'm printing obtained data (console.log(targetEl)) and the value is empty.

Comment: I'm printing obtained data (console.log(targetEl)) and the value is empty. Anny suggestion? @Hank X

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector which contains `t-attf-href` attribute ends with the id

```
$(`[t-attf-href$="${current_id}"]`).addClass('active');
```

Example:

```js
var id = 'kid_id';

$(`[t-attf-href$="${id}"]`).addClass('active').text('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a t-attf-href="/califications/kid_id" t-attf-class="nav-link"><t t-esc="kid.name"/>
  <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: none;"><t t-esc="kid.id" /></span>
</a>
```

Note: The `.text('test')` part is just for testing

Comment: I used the next code: var a = $(`[t-attf-href$="${current_id}"]`).addClass('active'); console.log(a); , and it obtains the selected "a->href" but the method addClass is not doing anything. This is the output "[t-attf-href$="14"]". Any suggestion? @Tân

Comment: @adriano009 After logging `console.log(a)`, if it pointed to the `<a>` element, you did it right. You can check the class name, if it really contained `active` class. The problem may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of the problem found.

```
var current_id = window.location.pathname.replace('/califications/','');
    if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(current_id, 10))){
        var $b = $('span.badge');
        $b.each(function( index ) {
            var badge_value = $( this ).text();
            if (badge_value == current_id){
                var active_a = $( this ).closest('a');
                $(active_a).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#middle_column > div > h1').html("No kid selected");
    }
```

Thanks for all the responses!